# Elsearticle: "Preprint submitted"

Tags: elsarticle, footer

how can I modify the footer of an elsearticle so that instead of "Preprint submitted to Elsevier", this text is "Preprint submitted"?

Ok, there seem to be new rules me showing my efforts of what I have tried so far. Good, this is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\let\today\relax
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
```

Does not show the footer any more but that's not what I want. I do not want the date to be shown but only "Preprint submitted".

So If try this ...

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\let\today\relax
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@pprintTitle}{\footnotesize\itshape
   Preprint submitted \ifx\@journal\@empty
\else\@journal\fi\hfill\today}{\relax}{}{}
\makeatother
```

doesn't help either.

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\let\today\relax
\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
    \let\@oddhead\@empty
    \let\@evenhead\@empty
    \def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\itshape
         {Submitted preprint} \hfill\today}%
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
    }
\makeatother
```

Date is not shown and I got the text I wanted to have.

Comment: Actually, the date *is* shown because of the \hfill\today part. To hide the date, removing that suffices.